# Kernel PCA similarity matrix analogy

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, covariance, similar-matrices, principal-component-analysis

The standard explanation to linear PCA begins with the covariance matrix.

That is, for a dataset $D$ of dimension $N \times d$, the covariance matrix is given as $\sum = \frac{D^{T}D}{N}$ where the eigenvectors and corresponding eigenvalues are determined.

Then, $D' = DP$ where $P$ is the basis matrix whose columns are eigenvectors corresponding to the covariance matrix $\sum$ of $D$.

But to my understanding, the aforementioned $D^{T}D$ is the dot product between matrix $D^{T}$ and $D$.

$D^{T}D$ may be expressed as $S = DD^{T} = K(X_{i}, X_{j}) = \phi(X_{i}).\phi(X_{j}) = X_{i}.X_{j}$ where the mapping function $\phi(X_{i}).\phi(X_{j})$ is not generally computed.
Indeed, the linear PCA is just a special case of the Kernel PCA.

The text I am reading says

1. Construct the positive semi - definite $N \times N$ kernel similarity function S using an off - the - shelf kernel function or other similarity matrix computation.

**Understanding**: Am I correct to think that $S = K(X_{i},X_{j})$ where, say, $K(X_{i},X_{j}) = (X_{i}.X_{j}+c)^{h}$?

2. Diagonalise the similarity matrix $S = Q \Omega^{2}Q^{T}$ and set the new $N \times k$ embedding $D'$ to the first $k$ columns of $Q\Omega$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalues. The default assumption is to set $k$ so that all non - zero eigenvectors of $S$ are included. Note that $k$ can be larger than $d$ in the non - linear setting.

**Understanding**: I am experiencing difficulties trying to understand the author here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A few things that I find confusing here. You seem to switch between $D^TD$ and $DD^T$ for no clear reason; did the same author write both of these? When you say the "dot-product", I'm not sure what you mean. For mathematicians, the dot-product of any two objects is a scalar. For computer scientists, the dot-product of two matrices is typically another matrix. When you refer to the "dot product" of $D$ and $D^T$, is this a scalar or a matrix?

Comment: @BenGrossmann

yes, he did.

He states that the covariance matrix $\sum = \frac{D^{T}D}{N}$ on page 75 of equation (3.13).

On page 84, equation 3.18, it is mentioned that the similarity matrix S can be expressed as $S = DD^{T}$.

On the dot product, this is a genuine confusion I am experiencing too. I believe the dot product of $D$ and $D^{T}$ is a matrix since $S = DD^{T}$ is a similarity matrix. I come from a math background so the dot product must be a scalar.

Edit:
Text is Outlier Analysis by Charu C Aggarwal